# Sharepoint Online - missing Search box on lists

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have created a List but I am unable to get the search box to display in order to filter/limit the data shown in the List.

I see plenty of screen shots for older SharePoint versions but nothing for Modern.  Did they remove this feature?  I feel like this is a basic idea but I am just not seeing how to add it.

I have tried looking at the `edit web part` of my List, at the `List Settings` and nothing talks about a search bar.

I am new to Sharepoint so any guidance would be appreciated.

This is how my Page currently looks.  The search box at the top says `Search this site` and I do not see how to add a search box for just my employee directory table.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The search box is now in the Microsoft 365 suite bar at the top of the page. The context of the search bar changes depending on your location in SharePoint, so if you're in a list it will display "Search this list":

[image]

**Edit:** From your screenshot, it seems you're trying to create a staff directory. I have created some instructions on how to create a staff directory using open source SPFx web parts here:

[Setup a staff directory in SharePoint](https://callum.technology/2021/02/setup-a-staff-directory-in-sharepoint/)

There is also a number of great search web parts available via [PnP Modern Search](https://microsoft-search.github.io/pnp-modern-search/).

Instead of adding the list to a page, you could also just direct users to the list itself where they will have the full list experience and the ability to search the list using the search box in the suite bar.

Comment: Hm, if I am looking at the list then I see the `Search this list` as you say.  However, if I embed this list into a page then I do not.  Is the expectation to not put searchable lists on pages?  Do you know of any good tutorials where maybe I could take a stab at adding a custom textbox with SPFx or something?

Comment: I added a screenshot of how my Page currently looks to the question.  You can see the search at the top says to search the page and not just the list.

Comment: I've added some additional information to my answer, which I hope is helpful to what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: That staff directory link you have looks like it is exactly what I needed.  I'll take a look at the PnP link as I haven't seen those before.  Thanks again!

Comment: I am finally getting around to looking into your suggestions.  The People Directory I was able to add easily enough although I am not a fan that it lacks the AD lookups.  So I started to look into the Staff Directory webpart and while trying to build it I am getting all sorts of errors about missing win8.1 SDKs and CL.exe.  Is the expectation that I need to download a bunch of older packages to get this to build?

Comment: They are both SPFx web parts, which only use client side libraries. You most likely need to set up your SPFx dev environment, if you are going to be downloading and building the web parts. Information displayed in the People Directory comes from the People search API, which ultimately comes from Azure AD. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview

Answer (score 0):

You could check from list settings > Advanced settings to see whether you have allowed items from this list to appear in search results:

[image]

Comment: That is checked to `Yes`